# Does Python support free-spacing regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

[This page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html) explains a mode of regular expressions, where "whitespace between regular expression tokens is ignored."

> Most modern regex flavors support a variant of the regular expression
>   syntax called free-spacing mode. This mode allows for regular
>   expressions that are much easier for people to read.

Does Python 2 / 3 support such mode? If yes, how can I enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is supported through use of the `re.VERBOSE` flag, [discussed in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE). Note that `re.X` is the short form of the `VERBOSE` flag.