# How to make Python ignore indentation and \n in re expressions

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to match a very large string like this:

```
"""
A=...B=...C=...D=...
"""
```

I used such an re expression to match the string:

```
'''
A=.+?
[^ABCD]+?
C=.+?
'''
```

As the re expression is very long, I split it into several lines according to `PEP8`. But python matches my implicit `\n` as well, i.e. it is trying to match:

```
A=(.+?)\\n[^ABCD]+?\\nC=(.+?)\\n
```

which is definitely not what I want. Furthermore,  I cannot use a pretty indentation because python matches that white spaces as well.

So how can I get out of this? I want pretty indentation and right matching.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python support free-spacing regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202394/does-python-support-free-spacing-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the `re.VERBOSE` (also known as `re.X`) flag when creating the Regex:

```
pattern = re.compile('''
A=.+?
[^ABCD]+?
C=.+?
''', re.VERBOSE)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE):

> This flag allows you to write regular expressions that look nicer.
>   Whitespace within the pattern is ignored, except when in a character
>   class or preceded by an unescaped backslash, and, when a line contains
>   a `'#'` neither in a character class or preceded by an unescaped
>   backslash, all characters from the leftmost such `'#'` through the end
>   of the line are ignored.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [re.VERBOSE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.X) mode, *you can even comment your re*.

```
a = re.compile(r"""\d +  # the integral part
                   \.    # the decimal point
                   \d *  # some fractional digits""", re.X)
b = re.compile(r"\d+\.\d*")
```